# Use Group Email (hosted by Google) to create an account on Google Play Store

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-play-store

I am trying to create a Google Play Store account but with a group email (hosted by Google). Is this possible?

For example, I have a group email on my Google Apps Business Console (hello@company.com) and I want to use this group email to set up an account on Google Play store. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have access to this email account (password)?

Comment: From what I know, group emails (hosted by Google) don´t have passwords, so that is one of the reasons why I can´t create an account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my own experience the Google group emails are not personal emails therefore you'll not be able to create a Play Store account with one. Also, you as an individual, don't have access to such an email account, no password access.
What you could do is to create the Play Store account using the email account which manages (the owner account) the group account.

Comment: Thank you ! That´s what I thought, but since I am new to Google Apps was not sure.